# Google Sheets GOOGLEFINANCE function won't return Current price of QQQX

Tags: price, google

Google Sheets GOOGLEFINANCE function won't return Current price of QQQX.  I've tried many exchange prefixes like "NASDAQ:QQQX" but still doesn't work.  Has anyone got this ticker to display the current price.  QQQX is a Closed End Fund (CEF).

Comment: Do you have to get it from Google specifically? I'd try other sources if they don't have it. (Websearch claims this is "Nuveen Nasdaq 100 Dynamic Overwrite Fund", which I know nothing about.)

Comment: I possibly could, but all other symbols work just fine, so I'd rather not change something that works for everything else.  Plus, I'd really like to know if it's a bug or something I'm missing.

Comment: I am having the same problem with my Google Sheets when using this function. It is likely a bug as other closed-end funds still work; e.g., CLM.

Comment: Which is why you should take this question to Google. If it's a bug, they're the ones who can fix it. If it isn't, they're the ones who can explain it.

Comment: QQQX doesn’t seem to exist in Google Finance, for some reason: https://www.google.com/finance/quote/QQQX:NASDAQ?hl=en

Comment: [QQQ](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/QQQ:NASDAQ?hl=en) exists, might be what you're looking for